# Is Sleuth tracing supported in Azure AKS?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-aks, spring-cloud-sleuth, distributed-tracing

I have an application that is going to provide tracing data with Spring Cloud Sleuth. I want to get this trace data to Azure Application Insights.

From Azure's documentation I understand that Sleuth traces are natively supported if I deploy my application to Azure Spring Cloud. However, the application is going to be running in Azure AKS instead. Is it still possible to view Sleuth trace data in the AKS version of Application Insights?

I don't have much experience with Azure (or cloud services in general), so apologies if the question is a bit silly :)

Comment: Theoretically it should work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-overview#application-monitoring

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc [Application monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-overview#application-monitoring):

By integrating Spring Cloud Sleuth with Azure's Application Insights, Azure provides powerful distributed tracing capability directly from the Azure portal.

This should work.